# Erro Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: na pasta wp-includes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Erro de JS na pasta wp-includes
Estou utilizando um plugin "Real 3D FlipBook" para gerar books fotográficos em uma determinada página do site.
Eu preciso que seja exibido vários books nesta página, porém é exibido apenas um book, os outros shortcodes não trazem o conteúdo dos outros books. Exemplo dos shortcodes:
[real3dflipbook id="1"]
[real3dflipbook id="2"]
[real3dflipbook id="3"]
É exibido apenas a do id="1"
Quando utilizo os comandos Ctrl + Shift + J para para verificar algum bug de JS, é gerado o erro "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ." no caminho --> http://www.meusite.com.br/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

A página que está com erro é:
http://www.elianesouza.com.br/album-gestantes

Comment: André, bem vindo ao StackOveflow. A nossa comunidade é um pouco diferente dos fóruns que existem por aí, faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) bem rápido para entender melhor o nosso modelo. Não é claro o que você está perguntando, veja [como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para o seu problema.

Comment: Além de melhorar a formatação (leia as dicas do editor enquanto escreve ou clique [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).) , talvez você pudesse explicar melhor **todas** as ferramentas/frameworks/plugins que você usa em seu site e como implementou isso (baixando você mesmo e instalando, gerenciador de pacotes do Wordpress, etc...). Também seria interessante informar qual ferramenta você usou pra *debugar* (CTRL+SHIFT+J pode não fazer sentido nenhum para um usuário de Mac, por exemplo.).